# Implement OpenVPN in Android

Tags: android, github, vpn, ics-openvpn

I recently bought a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) to create a VPN application, but it looks like there isn't any tutorial anywhere about it.

I saw the ics-OpenVPN project on GitHub, but I don't have any idea how to use it!

How can I connect to a Linux server from my phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, install [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) on your VPS server. Although I do not have experience to install OpenVPN on VPS server, I think you can follow this tutorial it looks easy *[How to install OpenVPN on a Linux VPS](https://www.skysilk.com/blog/2018/install-openvpn-linux-vps/)*.

After completing your installation, you will get the .ovpn configuration file. Now to connect with your VPN server from your Android app, you need an Android client software like the ics-OpenVPN Android client.

I have also developed an Android VPN app based on the OpenVPN library, and you can use my source code. It is open source. The instruction of changing .ovpn file is given in the GitHub repository.

GitHub: *[Cake-VPN](https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN)*

Comment: Was hitting a wall thanks for your github example! That was perfect for what I am doing

Comment: I am glad to know that.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be VPN? Or does an SSH connection with porttunnel satisfy your needs?

That is for example how I connect to services on remote servers. With the tunneled port, you are able to map the port on the remote server to your local system and access via localhost:<port>.

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to be a VPN connection, but I don't know if an SSH Connection would tunnel all the traffic through the server